# Rexnology puzzle

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the word I'm looking for?**

---

### [image]

Hint 1a:

> HR/VR

Hint 1b:

> H--------L R/V------L R

Hint 1c (I don't know if someone already figured this out but knowing this should be enough to solve the puzzle.)

> Horizontal, vertical. The "R" in hint 1a and 1b stands for a word.

Comment: If I may ask, is 'Rexnology' a standard word? I couldn't find its meaning anywhere.

Comment: @Jarvis No it's not, I just made it up.

Comment: I was fairly sure what R,U,D alludes to from the get-go, and Hint 1a was also clear. Still no idea what this is :)

Comment: @LukasRotter Hmm I think I know where you're stuck.. Try to figure out what the title could possibly mean. That could help. I'll add another (most likely the last hint) in a couple of days if it's still unsolved.

Comment: I think I figured out the title and still cannot make anything out of it.

Comment: @JLee I'll add a 'knowledge'-tag. The word I'm looking for is common knowledge these days. I could've added the "knowledge"-tag from the beginning but that could've been confusing since this knowledge only is required in the final step. But again, it's common knowledge these days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the word ...

> ... **BLUETOOTH**.

The two shapes ...

> ... can be completed by reflecting them according to the given directions: the first shape is complemented by its reflections to the **R**ight and **U**pwards. The second shape is complemented by its reflections **D**ownwards. Note that for each shape, the thinly outlined circle is now completed. (The letter R in the hints means reflection.)
>
>  In a next step, we can overlay the two completed shapes so that the circles match. Now remove the circle and we get a familiar shape.
>
>  [image: Three steps from two mystery symbols to the solution]

The title ...

> ... is a blend of **Rex** and **technology**. [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) is a **technology** for wireless data transfer. It is named after the Danish **king** [Harald Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Bluetooth), whose runestone is the logo we've just assembled.

Comment: ersyrpgvba! abg ebgngvba. v srry qhzo

Comment: Tick is yours! Well done 